# Java - ¿Cómo puedo añadir un número a un Int Sin alterar su valor?

Tags: java

para esto conozco un método pero en String que es append(), pero quisiera saber si existe un método para añadir un numero a un int sin alterar su valor?
un ejemplo;

```
int num = 15;

num (funcion para añadir) 3;
System.out.println("num: "+num);
```

saldría

num: 153

Comment: Multipricas el numero por 10 y le sumas el numero que quieres agregar: `num=(num*10)+5` y si quieres que sea una funcion: `public int append_number( int original,int append){return (original*10)+append;}` : `num=append_number(num,5);`

Comment: tambien podes pasar el numero a string, agregarle lo que queres (como sabes) y despues lo volves a pasar a numero... todo es valido....

Answer (score 2):

Una forma de hacer lo que buscas de una manera simple seria usar **Integer.parseInt**() y en este sumando la variable del numero mas un **String** vacío y el numero para agregar, por ejemplo:

```
int num = 15;
num = Integer.parseInt(num + "" + 3); // la cadena vacia es necesaria, por lo que se está pidiendo un String de argumento
    
System.out.println("numero: " + num);
```

Salida:

> > numero: 153

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
public class Main {

public static String mi_funcion(int numero, int numero2){
  String response = String.valueOf(numero) + String.valueOf(numero2);
  return response;
}
  
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
  int num1 = 15;
  System.out.println("num: "+mi_funcion(num1, 3));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes convertir a `String` para "concatenar" (usando `String.valueOf(...)`), posteriormente lo conviertes a `int` (usando `Integer.parseInt(...)`) para obtener un resultado de tipo `int`, por ejemplo puedes crear el siguiente método:

```
  public static int adjuntarNumero(int original,int append){
        return Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(original)+String.valueOf(append));
   }
```

llamarías de esta forma tu método:

```
      int num = 15;
      num = adjuntarNumero(num, 3);
      System.out.println("num: "+num);
```

Tendrías como salida:

```
num: 153
```

Comment: `return Integer.parseInt((""+original) + (""+append));` Debería funcionar también, ya puestos a hacerlo en una línea :P

Comment: Hola, se que funciona pero tu comentario es porque esto: ""+original es mejor que esto String.valueOf(original)? , usas un cast implícito pero se supone que para algo se creo String.valueOf(...) o crees que lo deberían eliminar del SDK?

Comment: No he dicho en ningún momento que fuese mejor, ni que deban eliminar nada del SDK. Mi comentario era eso, un comentario. Lo siento si te molestó, solo pretendía mostrar una manera más de hacerlo *"rápido"*.

Comment: Hola, solo se me hizo extraño, de hecho pensé que tenía algún problema pero veo lo comentas por escribir  rápido el código.